# ranges::view::transform produces an InputIterator preventing the use of std::prev

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-ranges

Consider the following code, which uses the Ranges library from C++20:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    auto transformed = std::ranges::views::transform(v, [](int i){ return i * i; });

    std::cout << *std::prev(std::end(transformed));
}
```

I was quite surprised to learn that (at least under GCC-10.3.0 and GCC-12.0.0) this code [gets stuck in `std::prev`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IAOwmkKQlabOP6cu).

What happens is that since the lambda doesn't return an lvalue reference, the `transformed` range iterators are classified as input iterators (see the [rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view/iterator) for `iterator_category` selection for `views::transform`). However, `std::prev` [requires](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) the iterator to be at least a bidirectional iterator, so I guess this code is actually UB. In libstdc++ applying `std::prev` to an input iterator leads to this function

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Distance>
__advance(_InputIterator& __i, _Distance __n, input_iterator_tag)
{
    // concept requirements
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
    __glibcxx_assert(__n >= 0);
    while (__n--)
        ++__i;
}
```

being called with `__n == -1`, which explains the observed behavior.

If we replace `std::prev` with manual iterator decrement, [everything works fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t6mMSBOcDFzOTZgt). Switching to `std::ranges::prev` [works, too](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BVWhksNDhVgvQR6H).

Now, it is clearly nonsensical that I can't do `std::prev` on what is just a view over an `std::vector`. While a simple solution exists, I feel extremely worried about this unexpected interplay between old and new range manipulation parts of the standard library. So, my question is: **is this a known problem, and should I really forget everything not in the `std::ranges` namespace when working with the new ranges, and rewrite all the existing code to make sure they work with the new ranges**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a random-access-iterator by C++17's reckoning. `transform` must return a value rather than a `reference`, and C++17's iterator categories don't allow that for anything above an InputIterator.

But this type is a `std::random_access_iterator` by C++20's rules, which allow proxy-like iterators on any iterator/range below contiguous.

`std::prev` is a pre-C++20 tool, so it works by pre-C++20 rules. If you need to work with C++20 rules, you have to use [the C++20 equivalent: `std::ranges::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ranges/prev).

> Now, it is clearly nonsensical that I can't do std::prev on what is just a view over an std::vector.

No, it is *necessary*. C++20's conceptualized iterator categories are less restrictive than those from previous C++ versions. This means that there are iterators that cannot be used in pre-C++20 code which *can* be used in C++20 ranges-based code.

This is why we have new functions for these things in the `ranges` namespace.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, know of a resource that summarizes the differences between the concepts and the old requirements? Maybe also with a rationale behind the changes.

Comment: @Timo Very interested in this as well, I'm a little worried about blindly changing all `std::X` to `std::ranges::X` in my codebase.

Comment: @lisyarus: You shouldn't "blindly" do anything. You should do what makes sense for your code. If you're using C++20 ranges/iterators in some piece of code, then that code needs to use C++20 algorithms with them, as C++20 ranges/iterators may not work in older pre-C++20 code.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course, this was an exaggeration. What I'm saying is that I didn't know about this incompatibilities between pre-C++20 iterators & C++20 ranges, and would like to see some comprehensive differences overview / migration guide (as opposed to, say, reading through the entire corresponding standard sections).

Answer (score 3):

Your transform returns a prvalue, so it *can't* be anything other than a [*InputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator). That's one of the main reasons that the iterator categories have been changed in C++20.

If the return value of your operation is a reference, [then you can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/042fcd24b992705b).